# crashing on select prepare statement in sqlite for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am trying to get specific record from my local database. For that I wrote below code.

```
- (NSArray *)selectFromActivityTableWithActivityId:(NSString *)activityId
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        sqlite3 *database = nil;
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) != SQLITE_OK)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "select * from activity_master where activityId=?", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"error in preparing select:%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            activityId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",[activityId longLongValue]];
            if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, activityId.UTF8String, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"error in binding..%d",sqlite3_errcode(database));
            }
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                int record_id = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                int someValue1 = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
                NSString *someValue2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                int activityId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3);
                double someValue3 = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 4);


                NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:record_id], @"id", [NSNumber numberWithInt:someValue1], @"someKey1", someValue2, @"someKey2", [NSNumber numberWithInt:activityId], @"activityId", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:someValue3], @"someKey3", nil];

                [arr addObject:dict];
            }
            if (sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"error in finalizing statement:%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            if (sqlite3_close(database) != SQLITE_OK)
            {}
            else
            {}
        }
        statement = nil;

        return arr;
    }
}
```

In this code I'm getting crash on
 `if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "select * from activity_master where activityId=?", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK)`

Not always but getting some time exception on this statement.
I don't know what is creating exception. 

Here is the screenshot of crash report on crashlytics.

[image: Crashreport]
Please help to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for keeping the exception secret. But the cause is most likely that other parts of your app have corrupted some memory.

Comment: As I said, I am not getting exception on everytime, otherwise I'll post here exception also. I really try hard to get that exception from today morning but not getting, Just got crash report from crashlytics.

Comment: What kind of exception?, there must be some explanation.

Comment: As I remember before 2-3 months, getting same exception at that time exception was `exc_bad_access`. But not getting this time when attached and debug with xcode.